# Integrated Windows 10 Explorer and Shell replacement

Tags: file-management, windows-10

What are some Windows Explorer replacements like Dopus or Total Commander that also completely replace Windows Shell, so the Windows Explorer isn't used anywhere at all?

For instance, if you ever tried Dopus or Total Commander, you know you can use it instead of Explorer, but if you need to use Save As or Open or any similar features in other applications, they still call on Explorer to do it because the Shell is not replaced. I am looking for a file manager that replaces Shell as well. I don't mind Explorer remaining on the computer, as long as I don't ever have to use it in any form.

I need this in a single piece of software because Explorer shares Favorites and other things with the Shell (for example, when you use Save As dialog, you can still see your Favorites on the left). I want to retain that ability.

Comment: As far as I know replacing Explorer as shell does not change the Open/Save dialogs.

Comment: @Robert okay, so how can I replace these dialogs with something better?